# How to customize TYPO3 styles.content.get Templates

Tags: typoscript, typo3-9.x

I've setup a simple FLUID_STYLED_CONTENT template with three `styles.content.get` elements. Is there a way to overwrite the template path of the element to load (e.g. here for the col=2 Element)? I can't expect from my customer to change the content element layout each time he/she sets a "slogan". The `contentSlogan` content is already fully rendered HTML text.

```
page = PAGE

page{

    # template
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {

        partialRootPath = {$resources}/Private/Partials/
        templateRootPath = {$resources}/Private/Templates/
        layoutRootPath = {$resources}/Private/Layouts/

        # fluid variables
        variables {

            content < styles.content.get
            navigation < lib.navigation

            contentTeaser < styles.content.get
            contentTeaser.select.where = colPos=1

            contentSlogan < styles.content.get
            contentSlogan.select.where = colPos=2

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A completely different approach like you proposed in your question is to set a default value for the layout in [Page TSconfig](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/TcaDefaults.html):

```
TCAdefaults.tt_content.layout = 7
```

Just like this it would set the value for each content-element, so you still have to check if the field `colPos` has the value `2` (I added value 3, to show that it works for several values too):

```
TCAdefaults.tt_content.layout = 7
TCAdefaults.tt_content.layout.if {
  isInList.field = colPos
  value = 2,3
}
```

Value 7 is the uid of the desired default layout and has to be adjusted.

This solution is not really safe, depending on the usage of TYPO3 there are situations where it never might work like intended, nevertheless in many cases it should be useful.

All the TypoScript snippets aren't tested and might still need some adjustments, my intention here is to show the general approach.